# Group collections and remove duplicates

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to publish a list that is generated from a group of collections. The collections contain a specialisation and a subSpecialisation (which is an array). I can produce the list however I can't figure out how to remove duplicates and correctly match the subSpecialisation to the specialisation.

EG.

**COLLECTION 1**

```
 "specialisation": "Accounting Firm",
  "subSpecialisation": [
    "Audit, Assurance & Risk",
    "Business Services & Private Clients",
    "Corporate Finance, Recovery & Transactions"
  ]
```

**COLLECTION 2**

```
"specialisation": "Accounting in Industry",
  "subSpecialisation": [
    "Financial Accounting & Control",
    "Management Reporting & Budgeting"
  ]
```

**COLLECTION 3**

```
"specialisation": "Accounting Firm",
  "subSpecialisation": [
    "Audit, Assurance & Risk",
    "Tax"
  ]
```

Path: `template.js`

```
specialisation() {
  let specialisations = Specialisation.find( {} );

  if (specialisations != null) {
    return specialisations;
  }
}
```

Path: `template.html`

```
{{#each specialisation}}
  {{this.specialisation}}
  {{#each subSpecialisation}}
    {{this}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

**Edit - Final result**

```
Accounting Firm
 - Audit, Assurance & Risk
 - Tax
 - Business Services & Private Clients
 - Corporate Finance, Recovery & Transactions
Accounting in Industry
 - Financial Accounting & Control
 - Management Reporting & Budgeting
```

Comment: Are __COLLECTION 1__, __COLLECTION 2__ and __COLLECTION 3__ actually _documents_ in _collection_ `Specialisation`? __UPD__ They obviously are. But final result you want to achieve still not clear.

Comment: Ramil, I'm trying to create a list based on the information that is published from the database. The list will be used to create a filter. See update. Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense now. There is no magic function to delete duplicates - you have to implement it yourself. First get array of your documents (`Specialisation.find().fetch()`). Then use `_.uniq` and `_.pluck` from Underscore to get unique specialisations and for each spec. find all required subspecs. Sry, have no time now to provide some code.

Comment: Hey Ramil. Any chance you could put up some code. I've tried implementing your suggestion but I can't get it to return the right subspecilisations.